# Объясните смысл данного участка кода

Tags: c#, unity3d

Unity добавили новый Package в их Package manager под названием Game Foundation.
Я захотел его изучить и наткнулся на интересный момент, который я не знаю.
Я бы хотел чтобы мне его объяснили(дали ссылки на ресурсы, которые могут более подробно объяснить).

Собственно фрагмент кода(несколько классов):

```
public abstract class BaseCollection<T1, T2, T3, T4> : GameItem
    where T1 : BaseCollectionDefinition<T1, T2, T3, T4>
    where T2 : BaseCollection<T1, T2, T3, T4>
    where T3 : BaseItemDefinition<T1, T2, T3, T4>
    where T4 : BaseItem<T1, T2, T3, T4>
{ ... }

public abstract class BaseCollectionDefinition<T1, T2, T3, T4> : GameItemDefinition
    where T1 : BaseCollectionDefinition<T1, T2, T3, T4>
    where T2 : BaseCollection<T1, T2, T3, T4>
    where T3 : BaseItemDefinition<T1, T2, T3, T4>
    where T4 : BaseItem<T1, T2, T3, T4>
{ ... }

public abstract class BaseItemDefinition<T1, T2, T3, T4> : GameItemDefinition
    where T1 : BaseCollectionDefinition<T1, T2, T3, T4>
    where T2 : BaseCollection<T1, T2, T3, T4>
    where T3 : BaseItemDefinition<T1, T2, T3, T4>
    where T4 : BaseItem<T1, T2, T3, T4>
{ ... }

public abstract class BaseItem<T1, T2, T3, T4> : GameItem
    where T1 : BaseCollectionDefinition<T1, T2, T3, T4>
    where T2 : BaseCollection<T1, T2, T3, T4>
    where T3 : BaseItemDefinition<T1, T2, T3, T4>
    where T4 : BaseItem<T1, T2, T3, T4>
{ ... }
```

Для чего нужно указывать остальные классы в классе BaseCollection?

---

GameItem - обычный класс, не наследуется.
GameItemDefinition - ScriptableObject

Comment: ну видимо потому что множественное наследование в C# не поддерживается, вот для разных типов базовых объектов и реализуют функциональность... хотя почему интерфейсами не пользуются не совсем понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы имеете в виду вот это?

```
where T1 : BaseCollectionDefinition<T1, T2, T3, T4>
where T2 : BaseCollection<T1, T2, T3, T4>
where T3 : BaseItemDefinition<T1, T2, T3, T4>
where T4 : BaseItem<T1, T2, T3, T4>
```

Это так называемые [ограничения](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters).

`BaseCollection<T1, T2, T3, T4>` - имеем [класс-обобщение](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-classes) , где T1, T2 etc - объекты удовлетворяющие ограничениям записанным в блоках `where` - в данном случае они должны быть экземплярами наследниками указанных классов.